# CSS image norepeat

Tags: css, image

I have a picture as a banner, I downloaded a better picture off google sadly it was smaller in width so it repeated itself 2 times and a quarter. I wanted it not to repeat. Aside from adjusting the size of the image to perfectly fit the designated height and width of my current css.. How can i prevent it from repeating, i tried background: no-repeat;  to no avail.. it cancelled out the image.

Have this css.

```
#banner{
   background:url(images/banner.jpg);
   float:left;
   width:500px;
   height:200px;
   border-bottom:1px solid #c8e0ff;
   background : no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: `background-repeat:no-repeat;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second `background` tag is overwriting your first one.  I prefer combining them into one tag.

`background:url(images/banner.jpg) no-repeat;`

Comment: I see, I took up my css designing class 2 years ago.. mustv forgot about that... hmm.. thanks.. ill keep that in mind..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
background:  url(iamges/banner.jpg) top left no-repeat;
```

You can replace the values of `top` and `left` with your own values.

Or `background-repeat: no-repeat;`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
background : no-repeat;
```

To

```
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```